# How to import postgres relations into django 1.8

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, import

I have an existing django database in postgres and it has several relationships. I have a new model in django postgres and I want to import some of the tables from existing database which have relationships. Do I need to map old fields to the new model? How do I preserve relationships? Is there a tool that helps in the process?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

It will create models from your legacy database.  Read more here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/#integrating-django-with-a-legacy-database