# Django Models with a existing Database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I'm new in Django, and I have a project, I want to use a existing database in postgres with more than 400 tables. But I have read the django docs and always you have to define a model like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

But I don't want to do this step to the 400s tables. Is there a way to just put the relationships between the tables without do the definition of each model and the migration?? Something like laravel does:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

Can you help me please??

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import postgres relations into django 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751402/how-to-import-postgres-relations-into-django-1-8)

Answer (score 5):

Use django inspectdb:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

Django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/).

Comment: but is it 100% effective??

Comment: Nothing is 100% effective, but it's from django official doc so you should give it a try before doubting about it. You might need to tweak your models, but it's worth to try compare to manually entering all models.

Comment: will it work if I put only the relationships? Django does not recognize all the fields by its own?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean `put only the relationships`. Please take a look at the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb. It explains in details what do you expect to change. Why don't you try to run it? If you run into problems, post it on stackoverflow and let people help you.